# Form`s data disapears when page refreshes

Tags: jquery, html

in this code i didnt find solution how to let table1 with data . when table2 displayed after refresh table1`s data disapeared !! how can i fix this ?

```
         <?php
$menucompare="";
if (isset($_POST["menucompare"]))
{
 $menucompare= $_POST['menucompare'];
 $table1 = '
                        <table id= "Table1" width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <!--SW - You need a tr tag around these headers-->
                                        <th >Weeks</th>
                                        <th ><p></p></th>
                                        <th > More Details</th>


                                        <tr id="tr">

                                                <tr id= "tr " >
                                                   <td  >gggg</td>
                                                   <td >kkkkk</td>
                                                   <td >
                                                                        <form name ="dets" method="POST" action="">
                                                                                <input class = "showt" name ="wnumber" id ="wnumber" type="submit" value= "More Details" />
                                                                                <input type="hidden" name="data" value="wnumber" />

                                                                                   <noscript>
                                                                                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                                                                                   </noscript>
                                                                        </form>
                                                                </td>
                                                </tr>
                                        </tr>
                                </table> ';
}
else if (isset($_POST["data"]))
{
        // put whatever db process you need somwhere in this if statement

         $table1 = '
                        <table id= "Table1" width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <!--SW - You need a tr tag around these headers-->
                                    <th >Weeks</th>
                                    <th ><p></p></th>
                                    <th > More Details</th>


                                    <tr id="tr">

                                            <tr id= "tr " >
                                               <td  >gggg</td>
                                               <td >kkkkk</td>
                                               <td >
                                                                    <form name ="dets" method="POST" action="">
                                                                            <input class = "showt" name ="wnumber" id ="wnumber" type="submit" value= "More Details" />
                                                                            <input type="hidden" name="row_id" value="value of row id" />
                                                                            <input type="hidden" name="data" value="wnumber" />

                                                                               <noscript>
                                                                            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                                                                               </noscript>
                                                                    </form>
                                                            </td>
                                            </tr>
                                    </tr>
                            </table> ';


        $table2 = '
                          <div id="Table2">
                                  <table width="100%" border="1"  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                          <tr>
                                                  <th id="wekkNum"> wnumber</th>
                                                  <th>Your place</th>
                                                  <th>Your arr</th>
                                          </tr>

                                          <tr >
                                                  <td>hhhh</td>
                                                  <td>kkkk</td>
                                                  <td>jjjj</td>
                                          </tr>

                                  </table>
                          </div>             
                  ';                   
}
?>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        /*Start Functions*/
        function displayVals() {
                var singleValues = $("select option:selected").text();
                $("#hiddenselect").val(singleValues);
                $("p").html("Procent of : &nbsp &nbsp" + singleValues);
        }
        /*End functions*/

        /*Start Ready*/
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $("select").change(function() {
                        displayVals();
                });
        displayVals();

                $("select#menucompare").change(function() {
                        $("#aform").submit();  
                });
    });
        /*End Ready*/
</script>
<form id="aform" method="post">
        <select id="menucompare" name ="menucompare" size="1" onchange="submitaform()">
                <option selected='selected'>Select one</option>
                <option value="value1" <?php    if ($menucompare == "value1") { echo " selected='selected'"; } ?> >Text 1</option>
                <option value="value2" <?php   if ($menucompare == "value2") { echo " selected='selected'"; } ?> >Text 2</option>
                <option value="value3" <?php   if ($menucompare == "value3") { echo " selected='selected'"; } ?> >Text 3</option>
                <option value="value4" <?php    if ($menucompare == "value4") { echo " selected='selected'"; } ?> >Text 4</option>

        </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="hiddenselect" value="<?php echo $menucompare ;  ?>" />      
</form>
<?php
if (isset($table1))
{
        print $table1;
}
if (isset($table2))
{
        print $table2;
}
?>
```

this is my whole code. 
hope there is fix for this , i have looked all posts but no similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_POST values are only available on the page immediately following form submission.

An easy way to keep user input through multiple pages is to pass it as hidden form fields.

So you would add a hidden form field to your 'dets' forms:

```
<input type="hidden" name="menucompare" value="'. $menucompare.'" />
```

Also, you'll have to get rid of the 'else' on line 37

```
else if (isset($_POST["data"]))
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST["data"]))
```

[Try this](http://pastebin.com/PT7G0h67)

Comment: waw , thanks so much its exactly what i want know , it works now :) thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
/*Start Ready*/
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function() { 
        displayVals(); 
    });
    displayVals();
```

That second `displayVals();` in this code snippet is triggering as soon as the page loads, which I expect is the reason for your error since upon page load nothing has been selected yet.

Your table2 will not display on page load or page refresh (which is just a forced page load) because you have the inline style `<div id="Table2" style="display:none;">`.  Similar issue with your expectation of the select option being retained... if the page refreshes, it is being reset to its default state, thus no selected option.

Comment: but i have in jquery `$("#Table2").show();
` to show the tabl2 . and if u see table1 works good even when refresh didnt disapear select option.

Comment: Your `$("#Table2").show();` is within a click event so it doesn't trigger on page load. "and if u see table1 works good even when refresh didnt disapear select option." ...Sorry but I don't understand what you're saying in that sentence.

Comment: i mean table1 works good , even when page refreshing , the table1 it doesnt loose its data. but when clicking button inside table1 , the page refresh and then disapear everything.

Comment: so how it will be then? you gave me reasons why it doesnt work , but solution i wonder how it will be thx .

Comment: edited , the problem is table1 loses data when table2 is displayed !!